# Need to select/activate option selected from HTML drop down list with VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

Although I have tried typical ways to select an option from a drop-down list, I don't get to where I want. Basically, I want to select from the drop-down with id "cboTipoValor" the value "95". If I do it manually, after selecting an option, a second drop-down will charge specific data depending on the first one. However, if I use `option.Selected = True` method, it won't activate the second drop-down

I cannot share the webpage because you would need to log in and there's no other similar element. I share with you the code of that specific drop-down and an image of how it looks like.

HTML Code:

```
<ul id="menuProductos">&nbsp;</ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-r">
    <div class="head-box">
    <h2>calculadora corporativa</h2>
    <span class="date">&nbsp;</span></div>
    <div class="form-base form-base-in">
    <form id="formCalculos" action="#">
        <fieldset>
        <div class="holder">
        <div class="column">
        <div class="form-instrumento"><fieldset>
        <h3>instrumento</h3>
        <div class="w-sel"><select id="cboTipoValor" disabled="disabled" name="tipoValor">
        <option selected="selected">Cargando</option>
        </select></div>
        <div class="w-sel"><select id="cboEmisoras" name="emisora">
        <option selected="selected">Emisora</option>
        </select></div>
        <div class="w-sel"><select id="cboSeries" name="series">
        <option selected="selected">Serie</option>
```

How could I know what is the action done on the back when I click the mouse?

This is my last try so far:

```
Set HTMLDoc = IE.document
Set dropoptions = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("select")

For Each op In dropoptions
     If op.getAttribute("id") = "cboTipoValor" Then
          op.selectedIndex = 9
          Exit For
     End If
Next op
```

Comment: use the elements tab of dev tools to see if there are any events associated with the select element. Also, inspect what happens to the disabled attribute when you manually perform a selection and mimic that with code e.g. setting a new attribute value.

Comment: You might have to trigger those events. For example if the site is jquery: `$('#cboTipoValor').trigger('change')`

Comment: Send a click to the *option* (not to the select tag !!!) you want to select . This will then trigger by the site js the second check box. You trigger the select tag with your code.  So you will need some afford to get the right <option> tag in the DOM. Have a look in the site HTML to figure out how it is coded.